Floating additional hair curve issue!
I've rigged this character and everything is working perfectly but the body hair/fur has this hanging extra clump of fur hanging on the viewport and renders! I'm using vertex group to mask the fur out of areas but the issue persists. I've redone the hair nodes many times and the result is the same! Also there's no extra curves on the faulty fur clump so i cannot delete it on edit/sculpt mode! Any assist would be grateful!
enter image description here
enter image description here


